# EasyLauncherConfig with name 'debug' not found

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using easylaucher library [Easylaucher library](https://github.com/usefulness/easylauncher-gradle-plugin) to add a ribbon on the app icon. I'm using kotlin DSL but when I apply the easy laucher configurations it throws `EasyLauncherConfig with name 'debug' not found.`
Here is my configuration

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin-android")
    id(BuildPlugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.starter.easylauncher") version "5.1.2"
}
android {
   //...
}

dependencies {
   //...
}

easylauncher {
    buildTypes{
        getByName("debug") {
            filters(
                customRibbon(label = "Debug", ribbonColor = "#FF0000")
            )
        }
        getByName("release") {
            filters(
                customRibbon(label = "BETA", ribbonColor = "#F18357")
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Anyone with a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of using `getByName(...)` I used `register(...)`

```
easylauncher {
    buildTypes{
        register("debug") {
            filters(
                customRibbon(label = "Debug", ribbonColor = "#FF0000")
            )
        }
        register("release") {
            filters(
                customRibbon(label = "BETA", ribbonColor = "#F18357")
            )
        }

    }
}
```